# mysqldump: Got error: 1066: Not unique table/alias: 'foo' when using LOCK TABLES when lower_case_table_names=1

Tags: backup, mysql

I'm trying to dump a MYSQL DB on a linux server (Centos 5.2 32bit, MySQL 5.0.45)

In /etc/my.cnf the following value is defined:

```
[mysqld]
lower_case_table_names=1
```

When I try and do a dump with mysqldump I get the following error:

```
[root@linuxbox backups]# mysqldump --user=root --password=secret   --result-file=/tmp/out.sql--all-databases
mysqldump: Got error: 1066: Not unique table/alias: 'foo' when using LOCK TABLES
```

I can't figure out what I need to do to work around this, and we can't set lower_case_table_names to 0 in my.cnf because that will break some things that require case insensative table names.

How can I do a mysqldump in this situation?  (or, another way to make a backup of the DB to file would work since that is the goal)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rename one of the conflicting relations.

Comment: Thanks - the DB contained the tables "foo" and "FOO" which obviously is a problem  when lower_case_table_names=1.  This had gone unnoticed until the dump because it was an unused table.